# Django Python Requests - Parse text/plain payload

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-requests

This seems like a stupid question, and probably is.

Say that I'm making a request to an API as follows:

```
r = requests.post("http://EXAMPLE.COM/api/randomstring")
## I've blocked out the real URL so false requests aren't made as it's publicly available
```

The specification for this API is that on every request, it generates a random string of 10 letters. If the request is processed successfully, the server should respond with **201 CREATED** and a **text/plain payload** giving the random string from the API database.

I have previously tried the following to parse the request, and add it to a locally stored database model:

```
new_word = r.text()
Words.objects.create(word=new_word)
```

But this gave the error:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I then tried simply:

```
Words.objects.create(word=r)
```

When I run this from a client, and then check the local database, it only shows as:

```
word: <Response [201]>
```

This means that obviously the request was successful, and a word is in the text/plain payload.

But how do I parse only the word from the payload, so that I am able to save it as (for example):

```
word: hskcudyhft
```

I know how to parse a JSON payload which is probably much trickier than this - which is probably why I'm overthinking it!

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
response = requests.post("http://EXAMPLE.COM/api/randomstring")
```

In order access Response Content, you should use [`response.text`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content), as `text` is an attribute of response object.

So change,

```
new_word = r.text()
```

*To*

```
new_word = r.text
```